# Proper Project Placement of ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, architecture, asp.net-identity

I am struggling to separate ASP.NET Identity from my main MVC project.  I created a class library and added the Identity NuGet package, then created a new class, but it's the `DbContext` that has me confused.  My understanding is that I have to create a `DbContext` that inherits from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`, but by doing that, does it not require a circular reference?  Below is my basic architecture and if someone could explain this, I would greatly appreciate it:

**MyApplication.Security**

```
ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {  }
```

**MyApplication.DAL (References MyApplication.Security for ApplicationUser)**

```
DbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

This project has to reference the security project to be able to have access to ApplicationUser in declaration of the DbContext.  This in and of itself breaks the separation of concerns model since the data layer is now dependent upon the security project.  What layer(s) do I have wrong?

**MyApplication.UI.Web.MVC (UI)**
This project has a reference to the security project as well as the data project since it requires the definition of an ApplicationUser (and corresponding profile) to be able to authentication and authorize a user for a specific controller/area/etc.  What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Just put `DbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` in the **MyApplication.Security** project.

Comment: So is it wise to have more than one DbContext in an application?

Comment: Or should I pass the DbContext from my DAL to my Security project?

Comment: It's fine to have one DbContext per domain

Comment: I see what you're saying now.  So, I would have various DbContexts (Security, Core Domain, etc.), since they have separate concerns.  Thanks for the insight!